# GlobalPlatform glossary definition

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

This is a part of page 7 of [Global Platform 2.2.1 card specification](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/GPCardSpec_v2.2.pdf).
May I ask you to help me recognize different between this terms?

[image]

Which one refer to *cap* files? Which one refer to *packages* and which one is for *applet's codes* inside a package?

As far as I understand :

- Load File Data Block = the *.cap* file
- Executable Load File = Packages inside the *.cap* file
- Executable Module = Applet's codes inside a package

right?

What about the other (Load File)?

And, Is it possible for a *.cap* file to contain more than one package? or each *.cap* file contain exactly one package? (In the other word, is there any Load File Data Block that contains more than one Executable Data Block)? If no, so why the GP defines two different word for them while both are the same)?

Answer (score 1):

**Load File Data Block** -- components in .cap files 
**Executable Load File** -- .cap files contains class extend Applet 
**Executable Module** -- the class extend Applet

one .cap file contain only one package,but may contains a few class extend Applet.
Also one cap file could just library package without any class extend Applet

Comment: What about **Load Files**?

Comment: This is a part of page 80 of _Development Kit User’s Guide
Java Card 3 Platform, Version 3.0.3
Classic Edition_ : **Note – If the CAP file contains components of multiple packages, you must use the
-package <package_name> option to specify which package to process.**
Doesn't it means that we can have a .cap file with multiple package inside?